# Сложение значений столбцов sparkSql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

У меня есть задача сложить большое количество значений примерно 20 столбцов, в которых могут содержаться Null. Какую функцию я могу использовать при сложении, чтоб не получить на выходе Null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно использовать [функцию nanvl](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#nanvl(col1:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,col2:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) из `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`, примерно так (не тестировал):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val zero = lit(0)
df.select(nanvl($col1, zero) + nanvl($col2, zero)...)
```